GeoMesa Accumulo custom iterator
I want to create a custom iterator and utilize it using GeoTools API.
Currently, I am retrieving data using DataStore and SimpleFeatures objects and trying to find a way to call a custom iterator I have created.
I have pushed a jar file that contains the custom iterator in geomesa-accumulo pod in the classpath. However, I cannot find how to call the custom iterator using the GeoTools library.
The goal is to move processing at the tablet level and I am doing that by creating a custom iterator. However, I cannot find a way (programmatically) to call or invoke the iterators using GeoTools API.
Tech Stack:
Accumulo 2.1.0
GeoMesa tools 4.0.1
Java custom client
https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/stable/_images/sampleQueryArch.png
I stored the jar file in the accumulo pod, but not sure how to reference or call the iterator. Is this through some configuration or is this done programmatically?

The GeoMesa GeoTools-to-Accumulo-iterator integration is based on custom query hints, which are used to configure Accumulo iterators at scan time. Adding a new iterator would require writing code to configure it. If the iterator would be generally useful to others, please consider contributing it to GeoMesa! (vs writing a custom fork)
However, if your iterator does not depend on query-time configuration, you could configure it to run on every query as a scan-scope iterator through the Accumulo shell.

A clarification: a "scan-time" iterator means one that is configured at the time of the scan (in the scanner client API). The setiter shell command sets shell config that causes shell-initiated scans to apply the iterator as a scan-time iterator. If GeoMesa is integrated into the shell, setiter to set a scan-time iterator might work. If not, you won't be able to set a scan-time iterator. However, the link above also describes setting iterators in table configuration at the scan scope. Those aren't "scan-time" iterators because they aren't configured in the scanner API, but they should work.

changed to scan-scope, thanks!

Thanks for the info. Now, I am trying to configure an iterator to a tablet through the Accumulo shell. I want to know how I can debug the log stuff from the iterator to ensure the iterator is functioning during the scan scope.

You should probably post that as a separate question, but you can use slf4j for logging, or you can enable remote java debugging on your tservers if that's what you're asking.

@Emilio Lahr-Vivaz
Created a new post, seeking help to validate the custom iterator execution.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78511101/geomesa-custom-iterator-execution-and-logging

@Christopher
Created a new post, seeking help to validate the custom iterator execution.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78511101/geomesa-custom-iterator-execution-and-logging

@FlameQpang - I saw the other question because I'm subscribed to the #accumulo tag, but this isn't the right forum for helping you with troubleshooting issues with your code or deploying your code. I suggest posting on the upstream Accumulo mailing lists (https://accumulo.apache.org/contact-us/ - specifically, the user list) for interactive help from other users and developers, or you can contact a similar forum for GeoMesa. StackOverflow is best used when asking specific targeted questions with clear answers.
